# php captcha code not working

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm using an old random() function for creating a validation code for an AJAX commenting system I found on the web (source code at [LINK](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/simple-ajax-commenting-system/) ).

The idea behind is pretty simple:

```
 function Random()
{
$chars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWZYZ23456789";
srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
$i = 0;
$pass = '' ;
while ($i <= 4)
{
$num = rand() % 32;
$tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
$pass = $pass . $tmp;
$i++;
}
return $pass;
}
$random_code = Random();
```

and then in the form, just before the SUBMIT button:

```
<label for="security_code">Enter this captcha code: <b><? echo $random_code; ?></b></label>
<input type="text" name="security_code" id="security_code" />

<input name="randomness" type="hidden" id="randomness" value="<?php $random_code; ?>">
```

My AJAX commenting system uses something like this for checking if a field is blank (ie. if there are any errors):

```
$errors = array();
$data= array();
[...]

if(!($data['name'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text'))))
{
$errors['name'] = 'Please enter a name.';
}

if(!empty($errors)){
[...]
}
```

so I wrote this:

```
if(!($data['security_code'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'security_code',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text'))))
{
$errors['security_code'] = 'You did not enter the validation code.';
}
elseif(!($data['security_code'] = $randomness))
{
$errors['security_code'] = 'You entered the validation code incorrectly. Please note that it is case sensitive.';
}
```

However when I click on the SUBMIT button after having inserted a random text in the validation code textfield ( test it by yourself at [LINK](http://www.flapane.com/guestbook/guestbook.php) ) I always get the "You entered the validation code incorrectly." message.

print_r($_POST) gives an empty array and then the script hangs after I click on submit: 
Array
(
)

What am I missing? The original captcha code gets lost at some point in the validation process (the 3rd and 4th blocks of code).
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you think `if(!$blah['A'] = 'B')` is different than `if($blah['A'] != 'B')` ?

Comment: I'd say no. However I've already tried the other way, nothing changed.

Comment: LoL :D
Could you please tell me what you are trying to do in that last block of code?

Comment: Just joking... The last block checks if the validation code field is either empty (it's already working well, the filter_input() function doesn't affect the second part of the last block of code, so I didn't wrote it here) or the user has inserted a wrong code.

Comment: Do you know that equality checking is done using `==` or `!=` and NOT with `!$blah['blah'] = 'blah'` ? By this you are assigning and checking if assignment went successfully or not :)

Comment: Thanks. I changed the elseif block with:    `elseif($data['security_code'] != $random_code)`   however the result is the same.

Comment: Put an `echo $_POST['security_code']` or a `print_r($_POST)` before you enter that last `if` block. Let us know if data you want is at least reaching the server...

Comment: Just `print_r($_POST)` and let me know if security_code is passed there - also, `die()` after the `print_r` and let me know the results

Comment: I was just editing the original post because I noticed that the data is not reaching the server somehow (`echo $_POST['security_code']` causes the script to stuck after I click on SUBMIT). Honestly I still don't know why, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you try putting `die` after the `print_r` as I suggested above?   
Also, paste `error_reporting(E_ALL);` above all your php scripts just after `<?php`

Comment: The original developer already included a `error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);` on the top. I added `print_r($_POST) or die('abort');` before the last `if` block, but the script still remains stuck when I click on SUBMIT.

Comment: Not `print_r($_POST) or die();` - I meant `print_r($_POST); die('done here'); ` Observe that they are 2 different statements, not one. I don't think that should ever hang!

Comment: Unfortunately it does. :(   I thought I'd better paste the source code at pastebin (form:[link](http://pastebin.com/FBvAf4Ht) comment.class.php:[link](http://pastebin.com/WR2kAV0G) submit.php:[link](http://pastebin.com/Dg1qy3Cz)

Comment: can you put that print_r line in your "submit.php" before you call `$validates = Comment::validate($arr);` ?

Comment: Also, replace the `error_reporting` line in all those files with this: `error_reporting(E_ALL); 
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: The script remains stuck, but now my error log reports `Undefined variable: randomness in /home/flapanec/public_html/guestbook/comment.class.php on line 129` that would be `if($data['security_code'] != $randomness)`. The same thing happens if I substitute $randomness with $random_code (which sounds strange to me). $random_code is definied in the first lines of the same php file.

Comment: As a sidenote, needless to say, if I use a constant rather than a variable, the verification method works: `elseif($data['security_code'] != 'test')`

Comment: Please try what I mentioned in my ["answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10849361/468746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your code [here](http://pastebin.com/WR2kAV0G), I see that the static function validate doesn't know the variable `$randomness`! From your submit.php, you are making the following call:

`$arr = array();

$validates = Comment::validate($arr);`

The function `validate` doesn't know anything about the variable `$randomness` unless you pass such a thing to it - it is in a different scope.

Try modifying the above mentioned code as such:

```
    $arr = array(); // no change here  

    $randomness = isset($_POST['randomness']) ? $_POST['randomness'] : '';   
    // Check for empty randomness before you validate it in Comment::validate
    // so that you donot verify for '' == '' there. 

    $validates = Comment::validate($arr, $randomness);
```

And alter the validate function as follows:

```
    public static function validate(&$arr, $randomness)
    {
```

I know its not the elegant solution - that would require few more things that you'd learn well for yourself, this is just to show you the way...
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your effort. Unfortunately it's not working and it shows "You have inserted the code incorrectly" even if I insert the right code. From error log I get: `[02-Jun-2012 18:42:08 UTC] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for Comment::validate_text() in /home/flapanec/public_html/guestbook/comment.class.php on line 174`. That would be  `private static function validate_text($str, $randomness)`

Comment: why did you send `$randomness` to validate_text? I wanted it only for `public static function validate(&$arr, $randomness)`

Comment: That's what you get when you want to edit php code when it's late and you're tired, instead of going to bed... Sorry, I clearly passed `$randomness` to the wrong function.   It works great and it helped me a lot in understanding how the whole process works, so THANKS A LOT! In the meanwhile yesterday I added Facebook-Connect support, a Twitter-like AJAX button (AKA "load more comments"), and automatic geolocalization for "location" textfield. I'd be honored if you could be the first to sign this new version of the guestbook [link](http://www.flapane.com/guestbook/guestbook.php) :)

Comment: Great :) Nice to know it works, so upvote and accept the answer so that people know this problem is solved and how it is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
<input name="randomness" type="hidden" id="randomness" value="<?php $random_code; ?>">
```

write:

```
<input name="randomness" type="hidden" id="randomness" value="<?php echo $random_code; ?>">
```

also instead of:

```
elseif(!($data['security_code'] = $randomness))
{
$errors['security_code'] = 'You entered the validation code incorrectly. Please note that it is case sensitive.';
}
```

maybe this:

```
elseif($data['security_code'] != $randomness) {
   $errors['security_code'] = 'You entered the validation code incorrectly. Please note that it is case sensitive.';
}
```

also, from where `$data` get its values? **$_POST, $_GET**?
`print_r()` it and also the `$_REQUEST` to light up.

Comment: Thanks, it's the same thing @Shrinath correctly also wrotetold me. Unfortunately nothing changed. Also, it seems that the validation code actually gets lost when it should be checked ny the validator. I checked the content of $randomness variable by displaying it in the output: `$errors['security_code'] = '<br />You entered '.$randomness.' the validation code incorrectly.';` and it seems to be empty (aka I get `You entered the validation code incorrectly.[...]` and not `You entered FOO_CODE the validation code incorrectly.[...]`)

Comment: the Random(); function works ok, so there's no way for having an empty $randomness in server; but what about the "Comment::validate_text" ?

Comment: It's related to another part of the script which checks for empty textfields using a filter_input() function, but it works well (furthermore I already tried to temporarly delete it and skip empty text-fields detection, but nothing changed)

Comment: Thanks. From all the INPUT_POST and no INPUT_GET at all in the code, it's definitely $_POST

Comment: then, call a echo"<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo"</pre>"; and place the resulted code in your original post (edit) to see.